# Good Multi-Thread Model for a bittorrent client?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bittorrent

I am currently writing a bittorrent client. I am getting to the stage in my program where I need to start thinking about whether multiple threads would improve my program and how many I would need.

I assume that I would assign one thread to deal with the trackers because the program may be in contact with several (1-5 roughly) of them at once, but will only need to contact them in an interval assigned by the tracker (around 20 minutes), so won't be very intensive on the program.

The program will be in regular contact with numerous peers to download pieces of files from them. The following is taken from the [Bittorrent Specification Wiki](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification):

*Implementer's Note: Even 30 peers is plenty, the official client version 3 in fact only actively forms new connections if it has less than 30 peers and will refuse connections if it has 55. This value is important to performance. When a new piece has completed download, HAVE messages (see below) will need to be sent to most active peers. As a result the cost of broadcast traffic grows in direct proportion to the number of peers. Above 25, new peers are highly unlikely to increase download speed. UI designers are strongly advised to make this obscure and hard to change as it is very rare to be useful to do so.*

It suggests that I should be in contact with roughly 30 peers. What would be a good thread model to use for my Bittorrent Client? Obviously I don't want to assign a thread to each peer and each tracker, but I will probably need more than just the main thread. What do you suggest?

Comment: You could always make it event-driven and just use the one thread.

Comment: Why not 1 thread for each peer? It won't hurt and will keep your code clean.

Comment: Will there not be an advantage to using multiple threads?

Comment: Using 1 thread for each peer will leave me with possibly 30 threads. Will this have a negative impact on the system overall, I don't want the program to hog resources.

Comment: @B4Z: Don't worry, it won't. The OS will note, that these 30 threads are not doing anything if they aren't. You can put them to sleep and only check every secon/10second/minute whether there is somthing to do.

Comment: Put it this way - every BitTorrent client I have seen has multiple threads.  30, or even 300, threads communicating with BitTorrent peers is nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Ah OK, I assumed that every thread would have a noticeable impact on the system, but now that seems silly :) Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a lot of need for multithreading here. Having too many threads also means having a lot of communication between these to make sure everyone is doing the right thing at the right time.

For the networking, keep everything on one thread and just multiplex using nonblocking I/O. On Unix systems this would be a setup with select/poll (or platform-specific extensions such as epoll); on Windows this would be completion ports.

You can even add the disk I/O into this, which would make the communication between the threads trivial since there isn't any :-)

If you want to consider threads to be containers for separate components, the disk I/O could go into another thread. You could use blocking I/O in this case, since there isn't a lot of multiplexing anyway.

Likewise, in such a scenario, tracker handling could go into a different thread as well since it's a different component from peer handling. Same for DHT.

You might want to offload the checksum-checking to a separate thread. Not quite sure how complex this gets, but if there's significant CPU use involved then putting it away from the I/O stuff doesn't sound that bad.

Comment: 'Having too many threads also means having a lot of communication between these to make sure everyone is doing the right thing at the right time'? Threads are often used to avoid exactly this kind of interaction. Windows IOCP is a mechanism to allow multiple pooled threads to process queued network 'completions' - it certainly is not 'one thread'. It's not even 'one user-space thread'. 'I don't see a lot of need for multithreading here' - maybe you know something that the developers of uTorrent etc. do not?

Comment: I disagree with your second point. IO Completion Ports can be used advantageously using a single thread. Consider for example a situation where the main thread in a BT Client has just finished downloading a piece, the thread calls the WriteFile function to write the piece to disk. If the file was associated with a completion port, the WriteFile operation could be called asynchronously allowing another useful task to be completed (on the same thread) such as sending requests for the next piece. After this has been done the thread can check to see whether the write operation has completed.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged your question [C++] I suggest [std:thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) of C++11 . A nice tutorial (among lots of others) you find [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html).

Concerning the number of threads: You can use 30 threads without any problem and have them check whether there is something to do for them and putting them to sleep for a reasonable time between the checks. The operating system will take care of the rest.

Comment: I understand how to use threads when coding. I basically want to know how many threads would be suitable for the tasks I described above and what each thread's assigned task should be.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood the word "model" in your title question. Concernig the number of threads I added a comment and will edit my answer to address this.